# iOS: Core data asynchronous data fetching and saving in chunks

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Is there an API to fetch data in chunks from DB and display (like a progress) in UI.
Vice-vera , can we do the same for saving ?

Comment: No...........
:(

Answer (score 1):

After reading some articles on **Core Data API**, i am able to achieve an asynchronous fetching behavior.

@Adam Fallon, you were correct when you said the without knowing the size of the content to be fetched, we cannot define the progress. But for fetching file size , we can simply call:

`managedObjectContext.count(for: fetch)`.

And for incremental fetching, we can use `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest` API.

**Sample Code**: [Core-Data-Asynchronous-Fetching](https://github.com/abhishekbedi1432/Core-Data-Asynchronous-Fetching)

**Blog link**: [Core-Data-Asynchronous-Fetching](https://abhishekbediblog.wordpress.com/2017/07/14/core-data-asynchronous-fetching/)

**Video Link**: [Core-Data-Asynchronous-Fetching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoFoPRfM2-0)

Will be exploring more for incremental saving.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to run your github sample. However, if `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` flag is enabled, it will have fatal crash. Do you know why? Here's the detailed - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70538970/why-i-am-getting-multithreading-violation-allthatislefttousishonor-for-this-simp Thank you